# remove a everything after a certain string javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi i have a string which builds itself up but i have some links that allow you to go back a section etc..now how it works is it passes the id in the query string.

i.e.

```
http://localhost:34523/buyhouse?house1=fd524fa0-a6de-e411-80c7-00155d105c00&house2=b6093a35-c2de-e411-80c7-00155d105c00
```

now i can find the id which i need to cut it down from when the button is clicked as the id is passed in but i want to remove everything after the id but keep everything in the query string before.

i.e.

if id `"fd524fa0-a6de-e411-80c7-00155d105c00"` was passed in the result i would want at the end is

```
http://localhost:34523/buyhouse?house1=fd524fa0-a6de-e411-80c7-00155d105c00
```

as it will remove everything after that id.

Is there a javascript way i can do this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you would need to find the GET parameters of the URL like so:

```
window.location.search.replace("?", "");
```

The above line gets the GET parameters, but removes the `?` at the start of the string.

You can then use javascript's `split()` function to split the parameters into an array:

```
var getParameters = window.location.search.replace("?", "").split('&');
```

Now you've got an array like so:

```
getParameters['house1=fd524fa0-a6de-e411-80c7-00155d105c00', 'house2=b6093a35-c2de-e411-80c7-00155d105c00'];
```

You can now use these array values to create your links:

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:34523/buyhouse?'+getParameters[0];
```

This would redirect you to:

`http://localhost:34523/buyhouse?house1=fd524fa0-a6de-e411-80c7-00155d105c00`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function myFunction(str, p) {
        var head = str.split("?");
        var res = head[1].split("&");
        var url = head[0]+"?"+res[p];
    return url;
    }
}
    </script>
```

str is your complete url:

str = "//localhost:34523/buyhouse?house1=fd524fa0-a6de-e411-80c7-00155d105c00&house2=b6093a35-c2de-e411-80c7-00155d105c00";

"p" is the position of the id you need.

Comment: Nice find! But it depends on the requirements of the OP, maybe (s)he needs to split after the second of three IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way I can think of is to use `indexOf()` to find where the id starts, add the id length to it and then use substring.

```
function cutOffAfter(mainString, delimiter) {
    var delimiterIndex = mainString.indexOf(delimiter);
    if (delimiterIndex != -1) { // If delimiter was found
        var endingIndex = delimiterIndex + delimiter.length;
        mainString = mainString.substring(0, endingIndex);
    }
    return mainString;
}
```